# Procyon decompiler uses a lot of memory when decompiling a lot of class files

Tags: java, memory-leaks, decompiler

I have created a java FX app to decompile hundreds of class files in my project using procyon decompiler. As more and more files are processed, the memory usage of the app hits 1GB in a couple of minutes. I guess this has something to do with processing string and the objects created on the process not being garbage collected?

Here is a sample code to reproduce the issue.

```
File file1 = new File("file1.class");
File file2 = new File("file2.class");

ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
DecompileUtils dcUtils = new DecompileUtils();
for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
    Callable<Integer> task = () -> {

        sourceCode1 = dcUtils.decompile(file1.getAbsolutePath());
        sourceCode2 = dcUtils.decompile(file2.getAbsolutePath());
        //do something with the result
        return 1;
    };
pool.submit(task);
```

The class containing the method to decompile the file :

```
public class DecompileUtils {

    public String decompile(String source) throws IOException{

        final DecompilerSettings settings = DecompilerSettings.javaDefaults();
        PlainTextOutput pText = new PlainTextOutput();
        Decompiler.decompile(source, pText, settings);
        return pText.toString();
    }
}
```

Edit : As I was going through the procyon source code, I've noticed that it was when creating the object of the class **AstBuilder** that the memory usage goes up abruptly. i.e when the **buildAst** method is called which resides in **JavaLanguage.class**

```
AstBuilder astBuilder = buildAst(type, options);
```

Comment: Why decompile more than one file at a time? And why collect the source code as a `String`?

Comment: I have to compare the production build with the source build to find the files that are different or that do not exist in one and not the other. This is to match the source code with the production version as the project was not properly maintained so far. I need the decompiled production and development source to compare the code. I have used checksum to narrow down the files that are to compared to reduce the overhead.